# Google Chrome popup with "XXX Started Debugging This Browser", How to turn off

Tags: wpf, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I wrote a browser plugin, the plugin used js code,
and then the browser appeared this pop-up window,
I learned from [this link](https://help.lipsurf.com/configuration/hide-debugging-msg.html#windows), you can use `--silent-debugger-extension-api`,
but this method does not apply to me, I want to let the user more simple operation, there is another way?
Like modifying the windows registry or something?

I am installing the Google Browser plugin on a wpf program, and I want the browser plugin to run js code without pop-ups :"XXX Started Debugging This Browser"

Comment: There is no other way, other than patching the binary or compiling it yourself.